# I can`t delete anything from my MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I try create my server on node.js+express and get error :

```
Cannot use (or request) retryable writes with limit=0
```

I try found answer in google and found what I need to specify in the connection string `retryWrites=true`
But i have it in my connection string.
Can you tell me how i can fix this bug?
my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const morgan = require('morgan')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const app = express()
const productRoutes = require('./routes/products')
const ordersRoutes = require('./routes/orders')

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:admin@rest-shop-e3hfo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true')

app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())
//headers
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE , GET')
        return res.status(200).json({})
    }
    next()
})
//--headers
app.use('/products',productRoutes)
app.use('/orders',ordersRoutes)

app.use((req,res,next) => {
    const error = new Error('Not found')
    error.status = 404
    next(error)
})
app.use((error,req,res,next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500)
    res.json({
        error:{
            message:error.message
        }
    })
})
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081 )
```

And module

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Order = require('../models/orders')
const Product = require('../models/products')

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    Order.find()
        .select('_id product quantity')
        .then(docs => {
            res.status(200).json({
                count: docs.length,
                orders: docs
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            error: err
        })
})

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    Product.findById(req.body.productId)
        .then(product => {
            if (!product){
                return res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'Product not found'
                })
            }
            const order = new Order({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                quantity: req.body.quantity,
                product: req.body.productId
            })
            return order.save()
        })
        .then(result => {
            res.status(201).json({
                message: 'Order stored',
                createdOrder: result

            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })
        })
})

router.delete('/:orderId', (req, res, next) => {
    Order.remove({_id: req.params.orderId})
    .then(order => {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Order deleted'
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    })
})

router.get('/:orderId', (req, res, next) => {
    Order.findById(req.params.orderId)
    .then(order => {
        res.status(200).json({
            order: order
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Use `findOneAndRemove` instead of `remove` in order to delete from the database.

Comment: Read the "comments" on the duplicate instead of the answers. The question probably should not have been answered by those who did and the answers are certainly not vote worthy. You don't want this option turned on unless you specifically want it. So if you don't know what a "retry-able write" is, then just remove the option from the connection URI.